# What's the best way to programmatically add and remove views and their controllers?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I'd love to see a detailed explanation on how to manage views programmatically. I'll provide an overview of how I'm doing it now and would like either comments on how my approach sucks or just an overview of how to do it cleanly and properly.

Basically, in my app's main view controller's `loadView` method, I first create a root view and set `self.view` to it. When I want to attach a controller, say, the first one that displays, I call this method:

```
-(void) attachViewForController:(UIViewController*)controller
{
    [self.mRootView addSubview:controller.view];
    [controller viewWillAppear:NO];    
}
```

Notice that I explicitly call `viewWillAppear` (I believe it wasn't automatically calling it), where I manually perform any animations to bring the view in (sliding in, fading in, etc). Is there anything wrong or strange with this approach here?

Now, when I want to leave this view and switch to another, I call a method to setup the switch:

```
-(void) setControllerSwitch:(UIViewController*)outgoingController 
    incomingController:(UIViewController*)incomingController
    delay:(float)delay;
{
    self.mOutgoingController = outgoingController;
    self.mIncomingController = incomingController;
    self.mSwitchControllerTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:delay target:self selector:@selector(switchControllerCallback) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}
```

At this moment in time, I've begun the exit animations for the outgoing view, and this method records the controllers and schedules a method that will perform the actual switch at the moment the outgoing view is done animating.  Like this:

```
-(void) switchControllerCallback
{
    self.mSwitchControllerTimer = nil;

    // remove outgoing view
    [mOutgoingController.view removeFromSuperview];

    // add incoming view
    [self attachViewForController:mIncomingController]; 
}
```

Is this a decent way to manage things? A few points:

1. I know I could probably instead setup a callback to trigger when the outgoing controllers animations end, but chose to just do it via an explicit delay param to leave room to allow me to cross fade views. However, I think calling `setControllerSwitch` early may in fact not allow crossfading because it would junk the old controller early and make it chop off its animation.
2. As mentioned earlier, I'm curious to know if explicitly calling `viewWillAppear` is a no no and there is a more appropriate way to manage view flow.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are manually implementing your own view controller navigation rather than using the built in pushing and popping of view controllers?

Answer (score 1):

Copied from Apple developer documentation but it help me lot to understand about views and maneging multiple views.

**Tips for Using Views Effectively**

Custom views are useful for situations where you need to draw something the standard system views do not provide, but it is your responsibility to ensure that the performance of your views is good enough. UIKit does everything it can to optimize view-related behaviors and help you achieve good performance in your custom views. However, you can help UIKit in this aspect by considering the following tips.

**Views Do Not Always Have a Corresponding View Controller**

There is rarely a one-to-one relationship between individual views and view controllers in your application. The job of a view controller is to manage a view hierarchy, which often consists of more than one view used to implement some self-contained feature. For iPhone applications, each view hierarchy typically fills the entire screen, although for iPad applications a view hierarchy may fill only part of the screen.

As you design your application’s user interface, it is important to consider the role that view controllers will play. View controllers provide a lot of important behaviors, such as coordinating the presentation of views on the screen, coordinating the removal of those views from the screen, releasing memory in response to low-memory warnings, and rotating views in response to interface orientation changes. Circumventing these behaviors could cause your application to behave incorrectly or in unexpected ways.

For more information view controllers and their role in applications, see View Controller Programming Guide for iOS.

**Minimize Custom Drawing**

Although custom drawing is necessary at times, it is also something you should avoid whenever possible. The only time you should truly do any custom drawing is when the existing system view classes do not provide the appearance or capabilities that you need. Any time your content can be assembled with a combination of existing views, your best bet is to combine those view objects into a custom view hierarchy.

**Take Advantage of Content Modes**

Content modes minimize the amount of time spent redrawing your views. By default, views use the UIViewContentModeScaleToFill content mode, which scales the view’s existing contents to fit the view’s frame rectangle. You can change this mode as needed to adjust your content differently, but you should avoid using the UIViewContentModeRedraw content mode if you can. Regardless of which content mode is in effect, you can always force your view to redraw its contents by calling setNeedsDisplay or setNeedsDisplayInRect:.

**Declare Views as Opaque Whenever Possible**

UIKit uses the opaque property of each view to determine whether the view can optimize compositing operations. Setting the value of this property to YES for a custom view tells UIKit that it does not need to render any content behind your view. Less rendering can lead to increased performance for your drawing code and is generally encouraged. Of course, if you set the opaque property to YES, your view must fills its bounds rectangle completely with fully opaque content.

**Adjust Your View’s Drawing Behavior When Scrolling**

Scrolling can incur numerous view updates in a short amount of time. If your view’s drawing code is not tuned appropriately, scrolling performance for your view could be sluggish. Rather than trying to ensure that your view’s content is pristine at all times, consider changing your view’s behavior when a scrolling operation begins. For example, you can reduce the quality of your rendered content temporarily or change the content mode while a scroll is in progress. When scrolling stops, you can then return your view to its previous state and update the contents as needed.

**Do Not Customize Controls by Embedding Subviews**

Although it is technically possible to add subviews to the standard system controls—objects that inherit from UIControl—you should never customize them in this way. Controls that support customizations do so through explicit and well-documented interfaces in the control class itself. For example, the UIButton class contains methods for setting the title and background images for the button. Using the defined customization points means that your code will always work correctly. Circumventing these methods, by embedding a custom image view or label inside the button, might cause your application to behave incorrectly now or at some point in the future if the button’s implementation changes.